# Visit Chat link

Tags: discussion

When I was reading some answers few minutes back, this "Visit Chat" link suddenly appeared.

When I revisit, I am unable to reproduce it again. Is this some AB testing experience?

[image]

Comment: I see a section for chat there every now and then, it takes you over to chat.stackoverflow.com. but i'm having a hard time getting it to show up now, and it never is just 'Visit Chat', usually it says something along the lines of 'There are currently n members chatting in y room. Join now'

Comment: am also refreshing the page & seeing different content everytime in there.. sometime chat stream showing up.. but never seen this hyperlink, thats why I asked..

Comment: Chat spam?  Never happens to me:)

Comment: My guess is it tried to pull up chat information, failed to do so, and then just displayed a default link to chat. I don't see any reason they'd do A/B testing around getting people to go to chat

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what is happening. They're getting a count of active users, and if there's only 1 active user or less, it displays 'Visit Chat', else it displays the normal one. `e.activeUsers > 1 ? $("#h-chat-link").text(function(e) {
            return 1 == e.num,
            e.num + " People Chatting"
        }({
            "num": e.activeUsers
        })) : $("#h-chat-link").text("Visit Chat")` So i'm guessing either you managed to catch chat inactive (highly unlikely) or it failed to get a count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes, seemingly randomly, a SO Chat widget (called an ad in the code) is displayed in the right pane. Normally what you'll see is a count of people currently active and then a chatroom or two will be displayed below it. However, in the event there are 1 or less active users, you will instead get the plain 'Visit Chat' link.

It's highly unlikely that there were 1 or less active users - certainly not this time of day - so I'd assume there was some form of caching or network problem on the backend that caused the active users count to be 1 or less at the point in time you loaded the page. It seems to be working fine now.